# How to filter an Object with Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have an array with some objects, like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "deleted": null,
    "disabled": null,
    "id": "456",
    "price": 970,
    "size": Object {
      "br": 35,
      "us": 3.5,
    },
    "status": "FOR_SALE",
    "type": "SHOES",
  },
   Object {
        "deleted": null,
        "disabled": null,
        "id": "123",
        "price": 1120,
        "size": Object {
          "br": 35,
          "us": 3.5,
        },
        "status": "FOR_SALE",
        "type": "SHOES",
      },
    ]
```

I would like to store all the prices that come from the objects in a variable, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
const prices = arr.map(o => o.price); // returns a new array with the prices
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*to start with:

    Array [
    Object {
    "deleted": null,
    "disabled": null,
    "id": "456",
    "price": 970,
    "size": Object {
      "br": 35,
      "us": 3.5,
    },
    "status": "FOR_SALE",
    "type": "SHOES",
    },
    Object {
        "deleted": null,
        "disabled": null,
        "id": "123",
        "price": 1120,
        "size": Object {
          "br": 35,
          "us": 3.5,
        },
        "status": "FOR_SALE",
        "type": "SHOES",
      },
    ]

isn't valid syntax for an array of objects.  Try this instead:  */

    myArray = [
       {deleted: null,
        disabled: null,
        id: "456",
        price: 970,
        size: {"br": 35,
                 "us": 3.5
                },
        status: "FOR_SALE",
        type: "SHOES"
      },
      {deleted: null,
       disabled: null,
       id: "123",
       price: 1120,
       size: {br: 35,
              us: 3.5
             },
       status: "FOR_SALE",
       type: "SHOES"
      },
    ]
 
 const prices = myArray.map(o => {return o.price})
 console.log(prices)
 
 var costs = []
 myArray.forEach(myFunction);
 
 function myFunction(item,index,arr){ 
 costs.push(item.price)
 
 }
 console.log(costs)
 
 var result = myArray.filter(item => item.price > 1000);
 console.log(result)
 
 console.log(myArray[0].size.br)
```